# A function that calculates the average length of hyphenated words

Tags: python, regex, average

I am trying to create a function that will find the average length of hyphenated words when the words are passed through the function as strings in python. The first part of the assignment was to locate all hyphenated words in a text file which I did using the code:

```py
Barrel = re.findall(r’\w+-\w+[-\w+]*’, pride)
```

Now I need to create a function that can find the average length of any hyphenated words entered into the function

Comment: Can you include an example of what `pride` might contain?

Comment: @timbiegeleisen pride was a text file of the book pride and prejudice where I used that code to locate all words that hyphenated. But I do not need to use the text file for the function. I just need a function that can find the average length of any hyphenated words entered

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `len()` and `sum()` functions to find the average length of all hyphenated words:

```py
import re

words = re.findall(r'\b\w+(?:-\w+)+\b', pride)
lengths = [len(x) for x in words]
avg_len = sum(lengths) / len(lengths)
```

Comment: Can I use this same set up for a function that finds the average length of hyphenated words not from a text file? 
Like: def average():

Comment: @Katies Yes; you would only need to replace `words` in my script above with whatever list of hyphenated words you want to check.